# Can't open ZIP file with double click

Tags: nautilus, 20.04, file-roller

If I double click ZIP file in Nautilus in mounted media like this path /media/martinb/Data/soft/Programas/01-joomla/extensiones/Componentes/Formularios/RSForm%20Pro/rsform-v2.3.16/Plugins/pkg_payment-v2.3.0.zip causes File Roller to miss path like the screenshot 
[image]

Is there something I have to configure in Nautilus or File Roller to fix this?

Comment: Does this file open in another location?

Comment: I can unzip it by rigth clicking then selecting "extract here", it's obviously an issue with the path containing %20. In my home folder, if I try to unzip a file like this file&name-1.0.zip fails too